# Extraer info de una linea de texto en PHP

Tags: php, regex

tengo un problema extrayendo información de líneas de texto, no logro separar la información, he intentado con Regex , preg_match (, substr ( , pero nada que se acerque .

Tomando como original las siguientes líneas de texto, las quiero evaluar para separar los datos:

```
#PRODUCTO   gallegas    #PRECIO    #LUGAR    #APELLIDOP    Lopez#APELLIDOM   Paz#NOMBRE  Jose
#PRODUCTO   #PRECIO    #LUGAR    #APELLIDOP    Lopez#APELLIDOM   Paz#NOMBRE  Jose
#PRODUCTO   #PRECIO    valor2    #LUGAR    #APELLIDOP    Lopez#APELLIDOM   Paz#NOMBRE  Jose
#PRODUCTO   #PRECIO    valor2    #APELLIDOP    Lopez#APELLIDOM   Paz#NOMBRE  Jose
```

Tomando en cuenta que los campos son #PRODUCTO ,#PRECIO, #LUGAR, #APELLIDOP ,#APELLIDOM y #NOMBRE y el valor de los campos es lo que sigue antes de iniciar el siguiente campo o terminar la línea.

me podrian dar una idea de como lo podría hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola!, Bien podría servir que le echaras un ojo a la función strtok de PHP.

Su función básicamente es separar tu cadena por tokens (basándose en un carácter) - items por ejemplo usando esta función tu cadena podría separarse de la siguiente forma:

```
$string = "#PRODUCTO   gallegas    #PRECIO    #LUGAR    #APELLIDOP    Lopez#APELLIDOM   Paz#NOMBRE  Jose";

$tok = strtok($string, "#");
while ($tok !== false) {
    echo $tok;
}
```

$tok en momentos tendrá por cada iteración PRODUCTO galletas, PRECIO, LUGAR, APELLIDOP Lopez, APELLIDOM Paz, NOMBRE Jose.

Claro puedes adaptarlo según tu lógica de acuerdo a cómo quieras obtener la información, pero creo que es lo más cercano a lo que necesitas.

Para más información, la documentación se encuentra aquí: [strtok PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtok.php)

Espero te sirva, ¡Saludos!